# EXCEL: How to check if a column of large data has any value different than TRUE

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of data, and have built several cross checks. In a given column I have logical tests that return TRUE or FALSE. I want to summarize a large amount of tests in one final TRUE or FALSE, so that any FALSEs can be spotted immediately.

I tried doing this by using `IF(E10:E400<>1;0;1)` and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, but it hasn't worked.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following formula ?

`=IF(COUNTIF(E10:E400,TRUE)>0,1,0)`

Hope this Helps.

Comment: That didn't work for me. But I have alternatively sorted my own problem out by creating a third column where i populate it with 1's for every TRUE, then I ultimately compare it to a COUNTA of the TRUE/FALSE column. Works fine. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out by creating a third column where i populate it with 1's for every TRUE, then I ultimately compare it to a COUNTA of the TRUE/FALSE column. Works fine.